# insert lightning-combobox value to text field using LWC

Tags: lightning-combobox

I want to insert a Lightning-combobox value in a text field using LWC.

I have used below syntax but it's not working. Please help me out.

html file

```
<lightning-combobox 
      data-id="trialCropDetail" 
      value={plntratevalue} 
      options={plntRateUOM} 
      variant="label-hidden" 
      required 
      onchange={plntUOMChangeHandler} 
      placeholder=""
 > 
</lightning-combobox>
```

JS file

```
plntRateUOM = [
        { "label": "SEEDS/AC", "value": "SEEDS/AC" },
        { "label": "LB/A", "value": "LB/A" },
        { "label": "KG/HA", "value": "KG/HA" },
        { "label": "SEEDS/HA", "value": "SEEDS/HA"}
    ]

plntUOMChangeHandler(event) {     
   this.value = event.detail.plntratevalue;
}
```

I want to use the value of 'plntratevalue' to custom field 'CD_RateUnit__c'.

Please help me out on this.

Comment: Could you please correct your HTML, which is syntactically incorrect, add the text field and also add the Javascript you have? This will make it easier to answer.

Comment: @FelixvanHove  Updated the description.. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close :) The Javascript would be something like this:

```javascript
plntRateUOM = [
    { label: "SEEDS/AC", value: "SEEDS/AC" },
    { label: "LB/A", value: "LB/A" },
    { label: "KG/HA", value: "KG/HA" },
    { label: "SEEDS/HA", value: "SEEDS/HA" }
];

plntratevalue;

plntUOMChangeHandler(event) {
    this.plntratevalue = event.detail.value;
}
```

Some remarks...

You should declare a variable that you're referring to in your code - be it `value` or be it `plntratevalue`. It is clearer. If you want the value to select entries of the lightning-combobox, the variable has to be declared explicitly.

It's not clear from your question, how you want to assign the value to a field `CD_RateUnit__c` of a Salesforce object; I've therefore ignored this part of your question.

The `data-id` attribute of the lightning-combobox looks unnecessary.

Finally, I've added a semicolon behind the "]" of `plntRateUOM`; even if Javascript doesn't require them, they are generally [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444080/do-you-recommend-using-semicolons-after-every-statement-in-javascript).